# python unpack zero elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

please consider following code snippet:

```
# state that items contains two or more elements
x, y, *_ = items

# state that items contains exactly two elements
x, y, = items

# state that items contains exactly one element
x, = items
```

Can I state that `items` contains exactly zero elements in the similar way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...why would you need to do that?

Comment: why can't you  do the check based on `len(items)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
() = items
```

`ValueError` will raise if `items` has more than 0 elements.

This is valid in Python 3.6:

```
>>> items = []
>>> () = items
>>> items = [1,2]
>>> () = items
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 0)
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: can't assign to ()`

Comment: It works in 3.6, but not in 3.5. But it's OK - will upgrade to 3.6.

Comment: it will give TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable if you use `() = items  # items= (1)`

Comment: @Gahan `(1)` is **not** a tuple, you need `(1,)`

Answer (score 0):

Not in a similar way but you can try to do access to the iterable's first item. If it raised an exception the iterable is empty. This method is famous as EAFP manner (*Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.*). Or you can check if iterable is empty or not by checking the boolean value if the iterable. With that being said, for an iterator you can use `next()` method, for iterables you can use indexing (`__getitem__`), etc.

```
# Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.
In [41]: try:
    ...:     item[0]
    ...: except:
    ...:     print("empty list")
empty list
```

# Or

```
In [45]: items = iter([])

In [46]: try:
    ...:     next(items)
    ...: except StopIteration:
    ...:     print("empty list")
    ...:     
empty list
```